# Whats the difference between " " and ' ' in c programming

Tags: c

Can anybody explain the difference between " " and ' ' in c programming? its getting to mi
example:

if i use ' '

```
date=type=='a';
if (date)
{
printf("its a date");
printf("%d",date);
}
```

it prints 1
and if i use " "

```
date=type=="a";
if (date)
{
printf("its a date");
printf("%d",date);
}
```

it prints 0

Comment: `" "` is a arrays of chars, `' '` is a char.

Comment: "a" is a string literal and `a` is a char primitive.

Answer (score 11):

Double quotes is for string and single quotes for character. But since you are using character in both of your samples then it doesnt make any difference. You can store character using double quotes but not the vice versa